# Possible to have 2 Feedburner RSS feeds for 1 blog (1 that provides full content, 1 for tease only)

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs, feedburner

I would like to syndicate a Wordpress blog on multiple sites. However, the way Feedburner is set up is to only provide the first bit of the blog so people will come to the blog for more and see additional content.

A syndication publication is asking for access to a feed just for them that has the entire blog post.

How do you or is it possible to create an additional feed in Feedburner for a Wordpress blog that delivers the full content (privately for those syndication sites that need the entire post)?

Would you simply burn a new feed, name it something else, and set settings to provide full content without disrupting the existing one?

Thank you.
Axel

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was asked but yes, sounds like in this situation you might want to create a second feed. The plugin FeedWrangler lets you generate feeds and customize their output.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-wrangler/